# Unable to use helper class with pytests

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

Helper Class

```
    class UserBuilder:
        def __init__(self):
            self.user = CustomUser.objects.get(email='random_email@test.com')

        def get_user(self):
            return self.user
```

Testing Class

```
    @pytest.mark.django_db
    @pytest.mark.parametrize('(user, output)', [
        (user_builder.change_bank_billdesk_bank_id(bank_name="IDN").get_user(), -1),
        (user_builder.change_bank_billdesk_bank_id(bank_name="IDB").get_user(), -1),
        (user_builder.change_bank_billdesk_bank_id(bank_name="SBI").get_user(), 1)
    ])
    def test_users_with_different_banks(self, user, output):
```

Error Log

```
    tests/trial.py:16: in <module>
        @pytest.mark.django_db
    tests/trial.py:100: in TestFunction
        user_builder = UserBuilder()
    tests/builder/user_builder.py:13: in __init__
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.get(email='random_email@test.com')
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py:127: in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:328: in get
        num = len(clone)
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:144: in __len__
        self._fetch_all()
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:965: in _fetch_all
        self._result_cache = list(self.iterator())
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py:238: in iterator
        results = compiler.execute_sql()
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py:838: in execute_sql
        cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:162: in cursor
        cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
    ../.virtualenvs/local_dev/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:135: in _cursor
        self.ensure_connection()
    E   Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
```

There was no proper solution available over the internet, so I tried whatever I came across.

I am unable to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the database outside of the test. This is forbidden. Instead of trying to fetch the data before the test and pass it as a parameter, do it inside the test. This will also avoid code duplication in `parametrize` marker.

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
@pytest.mark.parametrize('bank_name,output', [("IDN", -1), ("IDB", -1), ("SBI", 1)])
def test_users_with_different_banks(self, bank_name, output):
    user = UserBuilder().change_bank_billdesk_bank_id(bank_name).get_user()
    assert user.id
```